# Is it possible to leverage browser caching?

Tags: caching, google-analytics

I have ran a site through Google Page speed insights and one of its recommendations is to leverage browser caching for https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js.

Is this possible on a Drupal site?

Comment: Only if you 1. Get Google to change their cache expiry or 2. Serve a copy of the analytics yourself from your domain, and set appropriate headers. Probably not a good idea as you won't be keeping up with changes to google's code.

Comment: Ok Thanks for the response , if you make the comment an answer I will mark it as the right answer

Comment: @Clive May you add your comment as answer? Do you think the question is off-topic for us?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [one of the comments below the question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/posts/153691/timeline#comment_183610), this is possible only if you:

1. Get Google to change their cache expiry or
2. Serve a copy of the analytics yourself from your domain, and set appropriate headers. Probably not a good idea as you won't be keeping up with changes to Google's code.

Credits: [Clive](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/2800/clive).

Answer (score 1):

If you have a .htaccess file, you can add the following code at the top of it:

```
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/html "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"
ExpiresDefault "access 1 month"
</IfModule>
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
```

Comment: Google host this code themselves, a request will never hit your server so this won't do anything

Comment: is this only a drupal thing?I have tried this on joomla and wordpress sites and at least pagespeed sites like gtmetrix accept this and give me a leverage browser caching of 100%

Comment: Nope not just a Drupal thing - **the file is hosted by Google**, so only Google can change the cache headers. Sorry to shout, but it has been mentioned a few times already in this question :)

Comment: Yes, I got what you said in the first place, I just thought that this works, because I tested it on other sites and it worked, not only getting a higher rank at pagespeed sites, but actually loading the site faster without making any other change

Comment: Sorry to be the bearer of bad news, but it didn't work, not for the file we're talking about here - the only way to solve this issue for an external script is to make the script not external any more. That means serving it from your own server, which incidentally [Google do not recommend](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1032389?hl=en). See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29162881/pagespeed-insights-99-100-because-of-google-analytics-how-can-i-cache-ga for the canonical network question about this