# Leverage browser caching issue

Tags: caching, performance

I added some lines in my .htaccess file, following [Is it possible to leverage browser caching?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/153691/leverage-browser-caching-on-a-drupal-site), but Page speed tool still throws "Leverage browser caching error." for only images.

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! This question is too broad: You say you added some lines, without saying exactly which ones; You say an external tool gives you an error, but not for which files. Plus, you aren't asking any explicit question. Implicit questions don't work well on Stack Exchange.

Comment: Are the urls listed on the report a domain you have control over?

Comment: Just enanling mod_expires on apache will let the default .htaccess mod_expires rules work and give a good result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Read this article about [Leverage Browser Caching for Images, CSS and JS](https://www.siteground.com/kb/leverage-browser-caching/).

Add these lines to your .htacess file.

```
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/javascript "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"
ExpiresDefault "access 2 days"
</IfModule>
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
```

Also you can try

```
<FilesMatch "\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|swf)$"> Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800, public" </FilesMatch>
```

Comment: i added these lines in my .htaccess file but its not working.

Comment: did you try clear cache? 
and how do you test it  is not work?

Comment: yeah, i cleared all caches. after that i checked performance using google page speed tool.still it showing leverage browser caching proble for lot of png images.

Comment: did you try to restart Webserver(apache or nginx)?can you tell your website Url to me?

Comment: restarted apache server but still it says.and i can't able to share url.

Comment: i used below code it works clearly. 

"<FilesMatch "\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|swf)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800, public"
</FilesMatch>"