# Leverage browser caching

Tags: 8, caching

I'm trying to leverage the browser cache for my Drupal 8 site. I saw many posts regarding it, but whenever I edit the .htaccess file, there is still no difference in testing. This is my code right now.

```
 # Requires mod_expires to be enabled.
 <IfModule mod_expires.c>
# Enable expirations.
ExpiresActive On

 # Cache all files for 2 weeks after access (A).
ExpiresDefault A1209600

<FilesMatch \.php$>
# Do not allow PHP scripts to be cached unless they explicitly send cache
# headers themselves. Otherwise all scripts would have to overwrite the
# headers set by mod_expires if they want another caching behavior. This may
# fail if an error occurs early in the bootstrap process, and it may cause
# problems if a non-Drupal PHP file is installed in a subdirectory.
ExpiresActive Off
  </FilesMatch>
    </IfModule>
```

I read [Leverage browser caching issue](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/201244/leverage-browser-caching-issue), but I still don't get it to work.

I am using Apache 2.4.

```
httpd -M | grep expire 
[Thu Jan 11 15:27:29.472962 2018] [core:warn] [pid 11677] AH00114: Useless 
use of AllowOverride in line 173 of /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf. 
 expires_module (shared)
```

**Response Headers**

Cache-Control:max-age=0, no-cache, no-store
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Language:en
Content-Length:11829
Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date:Thu, 11 Jan 2018 22:50:43 GMT
Expires:Thu, 11 Jan 2018 22:50:43 GMT

Comment: You are sure the mod_expires module is enabled?

Comment: I believe so. This is the command I ran. 

>httpd -M | grep expire [Thu Jan 11 15:27:29.472962 2018] [core:warn] >[pid 11677] AH00114: Useless use of AllowOverride in line 173 of >/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf. expires_module (shared) –

Comment: First of all, there's more to browser caching than just the expires header. For instance, [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Expires) tells us that the Expires header is ignored when a Cache-Control:max-age header is present. Also, if you say it doesn't work, explain why you think it doesn't. Post the response headers of your front page. Not only the headers of the initial request, but also the headers of assets like images or CSS files.

Comment: Response Headers



Cache-Control:max-age=0, no-cache, no-store
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Language:en
Content-Length:11829
Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date:Thu, 11 Jan 2018 22:50:43 GMT
Expires:Thu, 11 Jan 2018 22:50:43 GMT

Comment: Apache configuration has no effect on the response from Drupal, that's only about static files. If drupal doesn't return a cacheable page if you enable it in the performance page as an anoymous user, then you have a module like captcha that prevents caching

Comment: Check what static components the page speed tests are complaining about. You may find that they are coming from an external source, such as Google or Typekit fonts. If so, your only options may be to ignore or serve your fonts yourself so that you gain control.